# Why do we need libnet_do_checksum? HTTP checksum doesnt work

Tags: http, checksum, packet

I understood that the tcp checksum calculates automaticly if we write 0 in the function libnet_build_tcp, so why do we need libnet_do_checksum?

I have an error, when I am trying to build a new packet. A regulat TCP packet(SYN,ACK) works fine, but an HTTP packet don't work, beacuse a tcp checksum error.
Do I have to use libnet_do_checksum?

Answer (score 0):

You use libnet_do_checksum() when you want to manually calculate the checksum, so you can check it before sending, for example.

Are you sure the packet carrying HTTP data has a checksum error? It can happen that the OS is using checksum offloading. Wireshark would report a bad checksum on the origin machine but the network card will compute it before sending the packet on the wire.